# linux find files with absolute path problem

Tags: linux, find, root, absolute-path

i would like to find file using absolute path.

I Tried with root and shows one result (the expected one). Same command with user account, shows more result.

**Find by root**

```
[root@server/]# find /opt -name 'marconi_000.csv'

/opt/marconi_000.csv
```

**Find by user**

```
[user@server /]$ find /opt -name 'marconi_000.csv'

find: `/opt/italiamacrozone': Permission denied

find: `/opt/anagrafica_indirizzo_nodi4.csv_1509009224.index': Permission denied

find: `/opt/geo_us_states': Permission denied

/opt/marconi_000.csv

find: `/opt/lookup_file_backups': Permission denied

find: `/opt/magazzini_lookup': Permission denied
```

what is wrong here?

thanks

Comment: It did work, as both user and root outputs contain the file you need: `/opt/marconio_000.csv`.  The rest are error messages of other directories and files that you did not have access to. You can suppress these messages doing `find /opt -name 'marconi_000.csv' 2>/dev/null`. This redirects the system error output, denoted as '2', to the null device (meaning it will be lost forever)

Answer (score 0):

You got the output of your find command both as root and user.
Look at the 4th line of your output as user, it has the find result.

With user, it gave you few errors, because user doesn't has file access in /opt, while root has all the permission.
As Emmef mentioned, you can ignore/suppress these warnings/error messages by redirecting stderr (standard error, denoted by numeric value 2) to /dev/null.

find /opt -name 'marconi.csv' 2> /dev/null

These errors are shown when user does not has read permission on the directory/file.